# Is it possible to register you own app as the default ringtone player

Tags: android, ios, media-player, default, ringtone

When an iOS or Android app is installed on their respective device, is it possible to register my app as the default for playing ringtones? Essentially replacing the built-in ringtone player with my own. If possible how is this done? Google has not been any help to far.

Comment: I think the user gets to make that choice, for security reasons, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

You can't on iOS.

iOS is a more locked down system than Android, and many things that would affect the core behaviour of the device is generally not possible.